# Ubuntu/Windows XP - Joint systems

Tags: dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to I remove windows but keep Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784/how-to-i-remove-windows-but-keep-ubuntu)

I have a computer sectioned to run both Ubuntu 10.10 and Windows XP but as XP refuses to log in (If I select XP the log in starts with the Windows logo being shown on the screen for a few seconds before the screen goes blank and the page showing the option of selecting Windows or Ubuntu the re-appears), I would like to clear it completely from the system and just run Ubuntu.

Can this be done, and if so, how do I proceed with doing it?

Answer (score 2):

Just login into ubuntu and run a tool like gparted where you can delete Windows's partition.
After that you've to edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg and delete windows's entry
Just like [this tutoria][1] say

[1]: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToRemoveWindows#Further Operations

Comment: You're welcome ... enjoy ubuntu :-D