# ubuntu installation alongside vista to uninstall vista later

Tags: windows-vista, preinstallation

if I decide to install ubuntu alongside vista, in order to try it first, can I disintall vista afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can instruct Ubuntu to claim the space currently taken up by Vista, and remove the dual-boot option so it will boot straight into Ubuntu. See the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46863/how-do-i-remove-windows-7-from-my-dual-boot-system-with-ubuntu).