# Windows installed after UBuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, software-installation, windows

I had Ubuntu 18.04 running, and installed windows after without doing dual boot process, and now the system does not let me boot with ubuntu. 
Is there any way I can 1) do the dual boot or 2) go back to the original status without formatting/deleting/destroying what is in ubuntu partition. 
Please help.

Comment: Are you certain that the Ubuntu partition still exists? The Windows installer has historically assumed that it would be the only OS on the entire drive and repartitioned accordingly...wiping all previous partitions in the process. That's one reason most dual-boot instructions specify that Windows should be installed first.

Comment: In Live Ubuntu run `sudo parted -l`, and post up output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) and [How do I remove Windows 7 from my dual boot system with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46863/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check with a Live-Ubuntu stick whether the partition still exists. if it does:
Look at the following thread:
[How do I run update-grub from a LiveCD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145241/how-do-i-run-update-grub-from-a-livecd)

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 different partitions, 1 for the original Ubuntu 18.04, and the other for the new Windows 10. I was able to boot only with Windows, not with Ubuntu.
I was not able to find a way to do dual after messing up Windows installation, but I got into the Ubuntu system with live USB, used GParted to delete the windows partition and now recover the original Ubuntu without harming any other.