# How do I remove windows10 from dual boot windows/ubuntu and keep ubuntu 18.04 as main os?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10

without messing up with hard drive how to peacefully remove windows 10 from dual boot containing windows 10 and ubuntu 18.04 . just want to use ubuntu os

Comment: UEFI or BIOS install? If from vendor with Windows 10, it will be UEFI. If an upgrade from Windows 7 it probably is BIOS, but could be UEFI. Back up Windows as we get many users who want to reinstall Windows for one app or game that only runs in Windows. If UEFI see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/794725/can-i-remove-windows-boot-manager-from-dedicated-ubuntu-computer You then can create a new ext4 partition where Windows was and use as data partition or maybe /home.

Comment: I just went through this on another question... don't remove Windows. You'll need it to run the occasional Windows-only app, or perform BIOS/firmware updates. If you don't immediately need Windows, just leave it alone, run Ubuntu, and be happy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove Windows 7 from my dual boot system with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46863/how-do-i-remove-windows-7-from-my-dual-boot-system-with-ubuntu)