# How do I completely remove Windows Vista after installing Ubuntu? 

Tags: system-installation, windows-vista

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to I remove windows but keep Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784/how-to-i-remove-windows-but-keep-ubuntu)

I don't like Windows Vista at all and wish to remove it

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in the standard way, by booting from an Ubuntu live CD/DVD or live USB flash drive and running the installer? (This would give you an Ubuntu system installed alongside Windows.) Or did you install with the Windows installer, called Wubi? (This would put Ubuntu's files on a disk image located inside your Windows partition.)

Comment: If you could post the output of the command `sudo fdisk -l` the people answering your question could make their answer more specific to what you need to do--which could help avoiding confusion.  Also please make sure you've backed up your files before doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Install "gparted" in Ubuntu and format the Windows Vista partitions using it.

Refer to the following figure:

[image]

Comment: You may want to at least distinguish between drives and partitions, as confusing them can be disastrous...

Answer (score 0):

After removing Windows partition, remember to update grub so that Vista gone away from boot loader. Use this command:

`sudo update-grub`