# Dualboot Ubuntu w/ WIndows: Deleting Windows

Tags: dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to I remove windows but keep Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784/how-to-i-remove-windows-but-keep-ubuntu)

So basically I started with Windows Vista then decided I want Ubuntu.
Now I have Dualboot using both of them, and want to delete Windows without starting over.
And because I've tried the USB boot to replace Windows but got an error, that I couldn't find an answer to.

Is it possible at all?

Simplified version:
I start with A
add B
so I got AB now
now I want to delete A
and only have B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OS Uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller) will remove your Windows partition and fix your Grub bootloader.

enter the following int he terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/os-uninstaller
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y os-uninstaller && os-uninstaller
```

The program will install and start, it will look something like this:

[image]

Just select  **Windows Vista** in the menu and the click ok.

[image]

Click **Apply** The program will do the rest.

You can read more about **OS-Uninstaller** [HERE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller)

P.S. this is how I removed my Windows 7 from my computer, so I know it works.

Comment: thank you wow, that was 10x easier than anything i expected

Comment: glad I could help, I was amazed at how easy it was myself.

Comment: For 14.04 `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/os-uninstaller` did raise Cannot add PPA error. Replacing it with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair` worked for me.

Comment: Does this work for 18.04?

Comment: @ablmf OS-Uninstaller works for any os you have on your system.  the link in my answer is still good the instructions should still work, the page I linked to hasn't changed so they procedure should still be the same

Comment: Didn't work for me. I get this prompt from uninstaller: Please use this software in a live-session (live-CD or live-USB). This will enable this feature.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to boot into the live CD and run `gparted` to delete the Windows partition and move your partitions around. You'll want to back up before doing this. `sudo update-grub` should then remove Windows as a boot option.

Comment: would also have worked, other persons was just a bit easier. thanks though

Comment: Absolutely. Never heard of OS-Uninstaller. Pretty cool :)