# How I do remove windows?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to I remove windows but keep Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784/how-to-i-remove-windows-but-keep-ubuntu)

I have installed Ubuntu onto my laptop and I am happy! Great stuff. How do I do away with (uninstall) Windows XP altogether please? Also.....can Ubuntu be installed onto my ecpc that is now redundant because of constant updates?! Do I just reformat the drive and connect a CD player with the Ubuntu iso on disk?

Comment: Welcome Nick, Yes is the answer to your second question, put the cd, follow the instructions and select "Use Full disk"

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove window you need to use [**disk utility**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-disk-utility/) or [**Gparted**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/) to format the partition that windows is on.
Once that has been done open a **Terminal** (using Ctrl+Alt+T) then use the following command

```
sudo update-grub
```

This will update grub and remove the windows entry.

Answer (score 0):

Install GParted and format the partition where windows is on.

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Then you need to edit GRUB to remove the Boot in to windows option.

Comment: -1 The OP is new to Ubuntu, you may want to edit your response and explain how to do the activities suggested

Comment: You don't need GParted to do that. Ubuntu comes with Disk Utility which can do the same.

Comment: also you can't add the freed space to your ubuntu partition with this method since it always has to be mounted. It would be better to use gparted from a live cd delete the windows partition and add the free space to the ubuntu partition

Comment: @Daniel Indeed, and even if you didn't want to add free space, it's dangerous to edit a physical disk's partition table while running an operating system from that physical disk. A live CD/DVD/USB is [the way to go](http://askubuntu.com/a/794/22949), for this.