# Can I (if so how) uninstall windows after completely installing Ubuntu 12.04 from a USB boot drive?

Tags: windows, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to I remove windows but keep Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784/how-to-i-remove-windows-but-keep-ubuntu)

I have successfully installed Linux Ubuntu 12.04 of my computer with the USB boot method. When I installed Ubuntu, I selected the option where it lets you keep windows on the computer in a separate partition so that you can have both Linux and windows as operating systems in the computer. Well, I decided I no longer need Windows, and I very much want to remove it so Linux has more space. Can I remove windows at this point and allocate more space for Linux, and if so, how can this be done? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I just thought I would write a clearer, and more noob friendly version of the others answers. :)

Steps are:

1. Open Disk Utility (Go to menu and search for it).
2. Identify your Windows partition. It should be a NTFS filesystem.
3. If mounted, click the "Unmount disk" button.
4. Click the "Format disk" button.
5. Choose Ext4 from the dropdown list.
6. Choose a name for the partition.
7. Make sure that, the "Take ownership of filesystem" checkbox is ticked, and that the "Encrypt underlying device" checkbox is not.
8. Click format.

Edit: Step 9: Open a terminal, by either searching for it in the menu or pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, and type `update-grub` and press enter.

10. Enjoy! :)

(Thanks to John S Gruber for Step 9.)

Comment: Should you end by running `update-grub` so that the grub menu item for Windows is removed?

Comment: That would be a good idea. :) I will add that straight away. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Disk Utility. Identify Windows partition properly and delete it. You can format it as Linux partition.

Once done, in terminal type the following:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

When done, reboot the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Just Go to Disk Utility. Identify windows partition properly format it as Linux partition.

Once done in terminal ( [What is a terminal and how do I open and use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-the-terminal) ) type:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda

sudo update-grub
```

When done reboot the machine.

Comment: Just updating grub should be enough, no need to reinstall it.

Comment: If you had install UBUNTU on separate dedicated partition of hard disk, then no need of reinstall of UBUNTU again. Just your windows will be formatted to LINUX partition if u format using Disk utility like GPART app in Ubuntu. And above command will make a GRUB to know which OS on your machine