# How to permanently migrate to 12.04 from Windows 7 without losing anything?

Tags: 12.04, wubi, windows-7

I recently installed 12.04 using WUBI to see if I would like it or not. Now I'm loving it and I want to permanently migrate to Ubuntu.

In the meantime I downloaded all the packages and customized it. Since I spent many hours learning and searching for codes and customizing, I do not want to lose any of those. But since I only allocated about 15GB, I definitely need to upgrade.

My first instinct was to increase the allocation limit but now I have everything I need and I do not want to run Windows at all. I have a lot of data in Windows (50GB). I absolutely DO NOT want to lose my custom settings in Ubuntu. Using a external drive is also an option but I would rather try not to.

*What is the easiest way to get rid of Windows 7 without losing any of my data in Windows and Ubuntu?*

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of doing this. The cleanest way is to backup your data in the Windows partition and Ubuntu /home in an external hard drive. Re-install Ubuntu erasing everything and restore the backed up data.

Alternatively backup every thing and try to migrate from wubi to partition following this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi .

It involves

1. booting from Live CD and manually creating the partitions where
   Ubuntu will go to
2. booting from wubi installation and...
3. downloading and running the script `wubi-move-2.2.sh`
4. Make sure migration was successful and you can boot both Windows and
   Ubuntu from respective partitions
5. Copy the data from Windows partition to Ubuntu partition

After this you will need to remove Windows and reclaim that hard drive space. See [How do I remove Windows but keep Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784/how-to-i-remove-windows-but-keep-ubuntu) for details:

6. booting from Live CD use gparted to delete windows partitions and
   reorganize Ubuntu partition (move, resize etc.)

As I said before, it may be easier to backup, re-install from scratch, and restore.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way is to use an external drive to backup all your data on a liveCD environment, after that use gparted to remove the windows partition and then move and resize ubuntu partition.

It'll take a LOT of time.

After everything is done type `sudo blkid` and the result will be something like this:

```
foo@bar:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Ubuntu" UUID="09e10b4a-9b98-4e9c-99b5-2e7024d9bd75" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="f9ca4a48-e7ed-4413-8877-fc3e0dfb0111" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="42D2CEE6D2CEDD73" TYPE="ntfs"
```

copy your ubuntu partition UUID then update `/etc/fstab` with your new UUID

`sudo nano /etc/fstab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=09e10b4a-9b98-4e9c-99b5-2e7024d9bd75 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=f9ca4a48-e7ed-4413-8877-fc3e0dfb0111 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Don't forget to update your swap partition UUID (I always forget it...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [APTonCD](http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/) to migrate your packages.

Then you can backup your /home folder to save your setting (at least most of them).

I would firt try to migrate it to virtual machine to know it work.