# Is it possible to use 12.04 live CD to repartition hard drive?

Tags: partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to I remove windows but keep Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784/how-to-i-remove-windows-but-keep-ubuntu)

I have a dual boot system Vista and Ubuntu. I upgraded to 12.04 and ran out of hard drive partition space for Ubuntu.

I a willing to blow away the Vista partition and the Acer recovery partition to make more space for Ubuntu since I never use the Vista and don't care about the recovery to Vista.

Can I use the 12.04 live CD to repartition the hard drive and save my current 12.04 installation?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the Filesystem you installed your linux on. Try to boot gparted and check if it shows you the possibility to resize this partition after you removed the VISTA / Recovery Partition.

But be careful. It is always possible that sth. bad happens. So make backup before you start. Make sure your batteries are loaded and the lappy is switched to a plug.

A Backup is possible with many tools. But this also depends on your filesystem you chose. And you will need an USB drive with the same size (or half the size - depending on your tool)

Comment: I have fat32 installed

Answer (score 0):

Without touching the existing Ubuntu installation, you can make room by adding a new partition, say `/backup`, using the space that you earn by deleting Vista and Recovery partitions. You can do it within your existing Ubuntu.

You can then move your some of your old data on to this new partition and make more available space in your root partition or to home area, if you have separate `/home` partition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely.

1. Boot into 12.04 LiveCD and run **GParted**.
2. If you really don't need the Vista partition, you can just delete it to gain unallocated space. Then format that unallocated space into ext4 (default filesystem for Ubuntu installation) or whichever filesystem you have on the Ubuntu partition you want to resize.
3. You can then select your Ubuntu partition from the GParted window and click on the **Resize** button (looks like a right arrow key) and drag the partition's right border to increase your Ubuntu partition.
4. Click on **Apply** (the check mark).

**Warning:** Resizing partitions may result to lost data.

For more information, check the following tutorials on resizing partitions with GParted:

[**How to Resize Partition?**](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/larry/resize/resizing.htm)
[**How to Resize a Partition using Gparted on Linux?**](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/2036-how-to-resize-a-partition-using-gparted-on-linux)