# I wanna partition more space for Ubuntu! (dual booting w/ Windows 7)

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, live-usb

So, I bought this computer recently, and immediately dual-booted Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with it. The other day, unfortunately, I ran out of the mere 20 or so gigs alloted to me (out of about 700). I'd like to repartition more space, but I'm running into a bit of trouble. I found this instruction:

[How do I remove windows but keep Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784/how-do-i-remove-windows-but-keep-ubuntu)

but ran into problems when it came to booting from the flash. It's just not recognizing the flash in my boot menu. I know that the flash works, I should add, because my girlfriend just used it twice for both of her machines. I'm sure that it's now obvious that I am sorely ignorant of this system admin stuff, so I'm not even sure if this is the best way to go about it. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: First of all, how did you install Ubuntu? Did you use Wubi or did you install on a separate partition? If it is the second, how did you install in the first place?

Comment: I used Wubi to install. Bad move?

Comment: Ah, so what do you suggest? Why would it not see the liveUSB?

Comment: It seems you need a liveUSB after all. Sorry. Did you try booting from your liveUSB by pressing F12 while powering on?

Comment: Otherwise try this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk

Comment: No, I only tried escape! Oops. Let me get back to you, good sir.

Comment: No, F12 didn't work. And how is this resizing helpful, exactly?

Comment: Isn't that what you want? More Space?

Comment: Hah, I didn't mean to suggest that you weren't being helpful, just that I don't understand how this Wubi virtual disc resizing works.

Comment: Very cool, thanks for your answers. I'll try this later this evening.

Comment: Everything worked wonderfully and much more simply than expected. Thank you for your answers. 

I should add for anyone else having trouble: The process can take quite a bit of time. I changed my allotment from 20 gigs or so to 400, and after over three hours without progress updates, fell asleep. With the process being finished in the morning, I was able to following the rest of the steps and confirm that it worked before breakfast. Thanks again.

Comment: Since it worked, why don't you accept the answer below as the right one to help others?

Comment: I tried, but I apparently don't meet the requirements. EDIT: fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot boot from a liveUSB you can follow a different procedure which actually creates a bigger virtual disk, copies all that is in the current disk in the new one and finally rename the old disk to replace the old one.

1. Boot Ubuntu and download [wubi-resize](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=wubi-resize-1.6.tar.gz)
2. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and type `sudo bash wubi-resize.sh 40`. Replace the 40 with the size you wish for the new Wubi disk.
3. Be patient until it finishes.
4. Reboot into Windows and go to the C:\Ubuntu\disks folder and rename the **root.disk** file **OLDroot.disk**
5. Rename the **new.disk** file **root.disk**
6. Reboot your PC into Ubuntu. If everything works you may delete the OLDroot.disk the next time you boot into Windows.

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk