# I want to remove Windows 7 completely and just use Ubuntu. How do I do this?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove windows but keep Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784/how-do-i-remove-windows-but-keep-ubuntu)

I want to get rid of a hacked version of Windows 7 on my laptop and just have Ubuntu.

Is this possible and how do I go about doing it?

Comment: Good choice :) Still, we will need more specifics to be able to help. Mostly: did you install ubuntu and windows on the same disk, in different partitions? Or on different disks? or did you install ubuntu inside windows?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/784/114818

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a dual-boot configuration between Windows and Ubuntu at the moment, just delete the windows partition with **Disk Utility** in Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub` in the terminal.

If you still have not installed Ubuntu and are planning to do it, just choose **Use Entire Disk** during Ubuntu installation (be sure to previously backup any important data on the disk).

Comment: He will need to recover the deleted space, possibly using bootable Parted Magic CD.

Comment: With either the **Disk Utility** or even **Gparted**, he can just reformat the deleted space on the disk to a new partition, or just extend the Ubuntu partition to use the whole disk. That is the simplest approach in my own opinion.

Comment: This should not be done on a live file system.