# Want to remove Windows 7 and retain Ubuntu istallation

Tags: installation, 13.04, windows-7

I installed Ubuntu and currently my laptop is dual boot(win7/Ubuntu). But now I want to remove Win7 retaining my Ubuntu Installations(software) I don't want to install Ubuntu with live CD. Please suggest some other method if you know one.

**Update based on OP's Comments**

sudo cat /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information. 
# 
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a # device
; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices 
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5). 
# 
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass> 
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation 
UUID=384594f2-ff10-499a-9ae6-2f85f6feeeaa / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1 
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation 
UUID=89a95801-318a-4d25-a0d9-76aceb07508b none swap sw 0 0
```

---

**Output of mount**

```
shubh10@shubh10-Aspire-5349:~$ mount
 /dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
 proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
 sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
 none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
 none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
 none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
 none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
 udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
 devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
 tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
 none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
 none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
 none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
 binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
 gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/shubh10/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=shubh10)
```

Comment: Are both operating system installed in separate partition. Use gparted or Disk Utility to check it. Reply here.

Comment: @SauravKumar is there no other way to check this? my internet data is limited and I can't download gparted right now.

Comment: Yes.. execute this command `sudo cat /etc/fstab` and paste the result on either editing your answer or here if it allows to paste such long text. You can use multiple comments to paste your result.  Use 10 lines / comment. :)

Comment: '# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=384594f2-ff10-499a-9ae6-2f85f6feeeaa /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=89a95801-318a-4d25-a0d9-76aceb07508b none            swap    sw              0       0
'

Comment: That's it? You don't have other information in `/etc/fstab` file? Reply if it is so?

Comment: ya that's it, and ya, I installed gparted from repositories

Comment: Simply running `mount` in the Ubuntu system will show if it's a Wubi system or a regular install. A Wubi system will have a mount point for `/` and will show other indicators of being installed on a `squashfs` virtual disk. So, please **edit your question** with the output of `mount` in the Terminal, run from within the installed system. Thanks! If it's a regular install, [remove it that way](http://askubuntu.com/q/784). If it's a Wubi system (meaning that you installed Ubuntu *while booted into Windows*), see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/635) (but reinstalling may be better).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, install GParted from the Ubuntu repositories.

And then you can just identify the Windows partition (usually, it'll have the NTFS file system), and format it.

I'd suggest to format it to your Ubuntu's file system, and then you can merge both partitions, to extend Ubuntu's free space...

Comment: but how do I know if I installed wubi or other partition???

Comment: how will i know if Ubuntu is not installed in same partition?

Comment: You can't resize an Ubuntu system's partitions from within the running system. They have to be unmounted first, and at least the `/` partition can't be while the system is running normally. Furthermore, while it's possible to create and remove other partitions on the same physical disk as the currently booted OS, it's not a very good idea--unpredictable results sometimes occur. So, to repartition the system drive, at least if changes have to be made to Ubuntu's partitions, GParted has to be run from a live CD/DVD/USB instead. (That's why GParted isn't present by default, on installed systems.)