# Remove Windows partition

Tags: windows-xp, partitioning

I loaded Lubuntu on a partition of my Windows XP & am ready to remove `Windows` and any unnecessary partitions but how do I do that?

This is what my partitions look like now:

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63    97684673    48842305+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        97685502   156301311    29307905    5  Extended
/dev/sda5        97685504   155254783    28784640   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       155256832   156301311      522240   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Is /dev/sda1 is the Windows partition? & are rest of the partitions needed?

Comment: Similar question has been answered http://askubuntu.com/questions/784/how-do-i-remove-windows-but-keep-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `sda1` is the Windows partition. You can delete it, but keep in mind that this will destroy all your data on it as well.

Also, if you've installed GRUB on that partition, you should reinstall it, to prevent boot issues (only execute the first command if you've installed GRUB on `sda1`):

```
sudo install-grub /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

But you'll have a bit of a problem because you can't extend your Linux partition with the free space as you can only extend partitions if there's free space on the right side of the partition you want to extend.

You can still extend using gParted (I believe) but this will take a **long time** and may cause data corruption as it will just temporary move your files and recreate the partition.

You can also choose to use the free space and mount it as your `/home` partition, so it'll all be used for your personal files.

Another option is to reinstall Lubuntu and choose to use the entire hard drive.

Comment: I have all my data backed up on CD, external hard drive, and USB drives, with duplication where desired.  I do not know if GRUB was installed on that partition.  Is there a way to find out?  Do I need to worry about that if I just reinstall Lubuntu to use the entire hard drive?

Comment: If you're going to reinstall you don't have to worry about it. I don't know how to check it at the moment, but I can look it up for you later if you want.

Comment: I will reinstall.  thx