# Wiping Windows 7 with Ubuntu 14.04 installed

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible for me to wipe my Windows 7 partition (and then re-install W7)?? I already have 14.04 installed and whilst I still want to have Windows on my machine, I have all my data backed up and I no longer need the data on the Windows partition. Is this doable?

Thanks!

Comment: See [How do I remove Windows but keep Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/784/how-do-i-remove-windows-but-keep-ubuntu) (also: [Remove Windows partition](http://askubuntu.com/questions/459313/remove-windows-partition)) for removing the Windows system and, if you want to install it (or another Windows system) afterwards, see [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/6317/22949)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is delete your "data" (files, pictures, etc), then just do a meticulous cleanup of the folders in which W7 keeps this stuff (My Documents, My Pictures, etc). This will allow u to keep your current W7 installation (and all updates). If you wipe-out (re-format the W7 partition), and then re-install Windows 7, the Windows 7 installation process will MOST CERTAINLY wipe out grub2 bootloader and install the W7 bootloader in it's place. This is not a disaster and can be fixed fairly easily by booting to a Ubuntu live CD and re-installing grub2.