# how to delete windows?

Tags: windows, uninstall

I realize this question must have been put before and there is answers lying about. I didn't manage to find them. I hope some kind soul will show me where to look.

How can every freaking aspect of windows on my computer be deleted?
Failed to do so during the actual installation...

Thanks/

Comment: If you open `gparted`, does it show an NTFS partition?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove Windows but keep Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/784/how-do-i-remove-windows-but-keep-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, this should be what you want

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToRemoveWindows

Comment: Not supposed to say so, but thanks anyway - guess that's exact what I asked for. Rebooting now...

Answer (score 0):

Just delete Windows Partition, or if you want, boot from Live CD and re-install Ubuntu and delete Windows (A option when you try to install Ubuntu), if you re-install make a backup of /home if deleted when installing Ubuntu again. (Please, search in Google, i just put what i THINK)