# "Stretching" `root` with Gparted on Trusty

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, gparted

Just as I installed Oracle Java 8, I registered a full 'root' on an Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop.
See the ext3 partition seen under `gparted` as `/dev/sda5` with mount-point `/` below.

In an emergency, I cleaned up old headers and images as well as some largely unused packages. Made some space.
As it is, after an automatic update took place this morning, I am now at only 364MB of free space in `/`.
Obviously I need to address this situation *now* .

[image: Gparted-SSD_20160301.png]

Getting rid of WinXp on that dual boot box, will give me 41.02 GiB of  new space. How-tos on AU (e.g. [[1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Vxnk.png), [[2]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784/how-do-i-remove-windows-but-keep-ubuntu)) and UF (e.g. [[3]](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1769489&s=7c1df298f3d9dd934f9535e8c87873c6&p=10871988#post10871988)) already cover that, and I already have `os-uninstaller` installed on a live CD for that purpose.

My only doubt related to `os-uninstaller` is: 
***Where to place the boot-flag: on `/dev/sda2` or on `/dev/sda5` ?***

Beyond that I've got getting rid of WinXP and [repairing boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) afterwards if needed covered. My ***real question*** is:

Using `Gparted`, can I actually move those 41.02 GiB of free space (now making up `/dev/sda1` and to be formatted as `ext3`) in such a way that it be merged (at least partially) with /dev/sda5 (`/`). Could someone explained the sequence of actions to be applied, following the pattern below  ?

It would involve the sequence:

- merging `/dev/sda2` with `/dev/sda1` as one larger ext3 partition
- shrinking the result to 477 MiB ext3 to the left (present `/dev/sda2` size)
- making the newly unallocated 41.02GiB space, now right of `/boot`, swap space.
- merging it with the present contiguous 7.45 GiB of swap-space
- shrinking the resulting 48.47 GiB swap space to 7.45GiB to the left.

But then how do I merge the resulting unallocated 41.02GiB space now right of `linux-swap` with the extended partition /dev/sda4` ?