# How to install ubuntu and remove windows

Tags: system-installation, uninstall, windows-10

Initially I have windows-10 in my PC. Now I want to remove it and install ubuntu. But RAM of my PC is 2GB only.remove

Comment: This may help you
https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: or else this will help you https://askubuntu.com/questions/784/how-do-i-remove-windows-but-keep-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu download](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
[Flash the usb with this](https://rufus.ie/)
Okay you need to download Ubuntu desktop first. After that Download Rufus (second link) and insert your USB drive to your computer. After you have done that run Rufus and select where you have downloaded Ubuntu(it ends in .ISO). After that just restart your PC with your USB inside and you can install Ubuntu then.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, Ubuntu can throttle the PC with 2...4 GB (same as Windows 10). LUbuntu has a primitive interface (LXQT), but it will perform uncomparably faster because it uses very low memory for internal needs. It installs the same way as Ubuntu (https://lubuntu.me/downloads/ - for LTS version, the latest version now is here; https://lubuntu.net/downloads/ - for the previous and future non-LTS versions).