# How do I Install Ubuntu for all my purposes by removing Windows 10 without loosing my other data files?

Tags: hard-drive, database, data-loss

I have installed a SATA 480 GB HDD dedicated for the C drive. This does not have any partition. I kept the old HDD with the PC and that has 4 partitions. I also added an 8 GB of RAM with the previous 4 GB one. All this is because of using both Windows 10 and Ubuntu at the same time and work with Database. Now, how do I remove Windows and use Only Ubuntu without loosing any data ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove Windows but keep Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784/how-do-i-remove-windows-but-keep-ubuntu) -- How to preserve your database depends entirely on where your database is located.  If it's on the volume that windows calls "C" and you delete that volume, then you will delete your database... Of course you keep great backups so that wouldn't be catastrophic even if you make a mistake

Comment: You start by making a BACKUP.

Answer (score 0):

Your best and the easiest option would be to access the Windows data on Ubuntu and keep a backup there and just erase the Windows disk.
And maybe this could help: [How do I remove Windows but keep Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784/how-do-i-remove-windows-but-keep-ubuntu?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I do not have Ubuntu in my PC. I used to run Ubuntu using the Virtual Machine. Recently, uninstalled that. Now, there is Windows only.

Comment: You don't need to have Ubuntu installed.  You would access it through a live session: the "Try Ubuntu" option using installation media.