# Can I uninstall every other partition and operating system and only have Ubuntu on my device?

Tags: partitioning

I have several operating systems right now. Only two of them work. My Ubuntu is a dual boot with Windows 10.

I want to erase everything else and only have Ubuntu. Is it possible? If so, how?

[image: screenshot of partitions with large unallocated area]

Comment: Based on how you describe it here I would say do a new install and just let Ubuntu take the whole drive. Boot from the Live Media USB and install Ubuntu. Follow this info https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: Is your goal to recover space on your storage device(s)? Please edit your question to show the layout of your partitions.

Comment: @OrganicMarble yes, that is what I want to do. I added the image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove Windows but keep Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784/how-do-i-remove-windows-but-keep-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the screenshot you added to the question,there is a large unallocated portion of the storage device adjacent to your Ubuntu partition.

Based on the comment that the goal is to recover space on the storage device, it would be relatively easy to

1. Make a backup of your data
2. Boot to a live USB
3. Use gparted to expand the Ubuntu partition left into the unused space

However this does not address removing the other OS's you mention. Please provide details on what they are and where you see traces of their existence.

Answer (score 0):

If Ubuntu is your first partition, it should be possible to free all other partitions and extend the first one to occupy the 'liberated' space. `gparted`  (probably as administrator) should help you visualizing how your disk is organized.

If `Ubuntu` is not your first partitiion, it might still be possible, but you'll have remove the other partitions, and move `ubuntu` down, then extend.

Be careful... And read about what `gparted` does.

I you have little experience, and have little or no data, do what @david commented above!